# How to predict the clusters for new data using HCPC with FactoMineR in R

Tags: r, predict, hierarchical-clustering

I clustered some data I have using FactoMineR::HCPC in R and now I am trying to cluster new data using the model I have trained. However I can not find a function that will give me such prediction. So far I've been able to see that I can use predict.PCA with my new data set and the previous PCA I implemented on the trainig data set and use that result on the function HCPC. I know that for kmenas there exist a predict which will take as input the trained model and the new data. Does anybody know if there is an equivalent for HCPC?